# Weird behaviour when creating tasks within lists (asyncio)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```python
import asyncio
import random


async def producer(q: asyncio.Queue):
    for _ in range(100):
        await q.put(random.randint(1, 10))


async def consumer(q: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        num = await q.get()
        print("Got From Queue: ", num)
        q.task_done()


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    pr = asyncio.create_task(producer(q))
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(q)) for _ in range(10)]

    await pr
    await q.join()
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I created this script to replicate a simplified version of my problem.
so this is a very basic producer-consumer type of script, and this works just fine
however if an exception occurs inside the consumer, the script freezes.
for example, If I modify the consumer script like so:

```python
async def consumer(q: asyncio.Queue):
    raise Exception
    while True:
        num = await q.get()
        print("Got From Queue: ", num)
        q.task_done()
```

when I run the script now it freezes and no exceptions get thrown.
However, If I change the main script to generate all the consumer tasks in a for loop instead of generating them through a list comprehension like so:

```python
async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    pr = asyncio.create_task(producer(q))
    # consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(q)) for _ in range(10)]
    for _ in range(10):
        asyncio.create_task(consumer(q))

    await pr
    await q.join()
```

It throws 10 exceptions of type Exception, as expected behavior.
my 2 questions are:

1. Why does this strange behaviour happen?
2. In my actual script, I want to use exception handling, so I'm using now the for-loop approach. However, In this approach, I don't have references to all the consumer tasks, so I can't cancel them when I want. How can I do that? (Simply appending them to a list after creation replicates the original problem)
   I am completely clueless, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the use of a list comprehension instead of a for loop has any impact on this.

You should handle the exception in the consumer and call `task_done()` for each `get()`, otherwise you'll experience the current behaviour where `q.join()` will block/wait for unfinished tasks:

[task_done()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.task_done)

> If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have
> been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for every
> item that had been put() into the queue).

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio
import random


async def producer(q):
    for _ in range(10):
        await q.put(random.randint(1, 10))


async def consumer(q):
    while True:
        num = await q.get()

        try:
            if num in (5, 8):
                raise Exception("ERROR")

            print(f"Working on: {num}")
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"{num}: {exc}")
        finally:
            q.task_done()


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    pr = asyncio.create_task(producer(q))

    tasks = []

    for _ in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(consumer(q)))

    await pr
    await q.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
Working on: 7
Working on: 4
Working on: 4
Working on: 4
Working on: 1
Working on: 3
8: ERROR
Working on: 6
5: ERROR
Working on: 4
```